# How to move an entire branch to the main branch

Tags: github

I have the following branches :

[image]

I wish to make my client-rework branch the master branch. I dont want to merge it, I want to entirely replace the master branch with the newest i created. I also dont want the master branch remove, ideally it would be renamed to something like master-old or something. Is this possible or am i asking something dumb here.

Comment: Update: can i just rename my branch to master and the old one to master-old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set your client-rework to be the default branch in setting, tab branches. like in my case below, i set develop as the default branch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing  master branch is by default protected. You have to remove that from settings, it depends which git flavor you are using. and you should not delete because that is how industry practices work. you may try git checkout master or some other branch

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Github you have to change the default branch first.

[image: Change default branch]

After that you need to rename the local `client-rework` branch to `master`:

```
$ git branch -m master master-old
$ git branch -m client-rework master
```

Now push the branches to origin remote:

```
$ git push origin HEAD
```